# Spring boot + cassandra 3.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

Is the way to use cassandra 3.x with Spring boot?
I was trying to use new version of spring-data-cassandra 1.5.0 while cassandra driver 3.0 is supported, but Spring boot change the dependency to 2.1.9.
I also tried to use spring-data-cassandra 1.5.0 without Spring boot, but there is not a reference documentation i i have got some errors.
I've spent whole day for trying to make it works, but there are no effects.
Maybe someone have some samples or information that can help me to run cassandra cluster on Spring boot :)

Comment: in the maven pom, or grade build file for your spring-boot application you might be able to exclude 2.1.9 cassandra from the spring-boot calandra dependency, and then include cassandra 3.  My understanding is spring-boot shouldn't get in your way, its just there to spin up and connect the dependencies you add to the class path.

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle? Can you share your pom.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: What is the current situation?

Comment: Share your code, it will be easier to help you